# React component still shows up when it should have been hidden by a setting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Pseudo-code:

```
const foo = true
const isVisible = true // Possible values are true, false and undefined

// Implementation A
<Item
  visible = {foo && isVisible}
/>

// Implementation B
{isVisible && (<Item
  visible = {foo}
/>)}

const Item = ({visible = true, bar = {}}) => 
 (!!visible && (<Item>{bar}</Item>)) 
 || null;
```

Given this arrangements, both implementation A and B should have shown the Item when `isVisible = true` and hides it when `isVisible = false` or `isVisible = undefined`, yet the actual results I'm getting is that the it works for true/false, but A shows up when undefined and B hides it, and I'm not really sure why.

I hope this is all the relevant context, let me know if I potentially missed anything.

Comment: The value of ```visible = {foo && isVisible}``` when ```foo = true``` and ```isVisible = undefined``` is undefined.

So when you pass undefined value to props, component will get the default value for it. And with your case, value of visible is true.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPmSI.png

Comment: But why do you render the Item inside the component Item here? It will make your browser crash because of the infinite loop rendering :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me explain the behavior of both implementations A and B when `isVisible` is `undefined`.

**Implementation A:**

```js
<Item
  visible = {foo && isVisible}
/>
```

In this case, when `isVisible` is `undefined`, the `visible` prop evaluates to `true && undefined`, which results in `undefined`. Since the `Item` component has a default value of `true` for the `visible` prop, the expression `visible = true` assigns the default value, and the `Item` is shown.

**Implementation B:**

```js
{isVisible && (<Item
  visible = {foo}
/>)}
```

In this case, when `isVisible` is `undefined`, the expression `{isVisible && ...}` evaluates to `undefined`, and the `Item` component is not rendered at all. This is why the `Item` is hidden in this case.

So, all in all the difference in behaviour is due to how the `visible` prop is being passed in each implementation.

Comment: I see, that makes a lot of sense. Thank you for your help.